# Rviz Marker Triangle List: bad shader

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization-msgs, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why if i create a Mesh triangle-by-triangle  by using *visualization_msgs::Marker* (type=TRIANGLE_LIST) the shader doesn't take into account normals ? Surface shader is not working. See attached image:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246651/rviz-marker-triangle-list:-bad-shader/) by [m4nh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28371/m4nh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-10-28**:
Does it look like that from all angles? Sometimes the order of the points will determine the normal face, i.e. clockwise will give you a normal in one direction and counterclockwise will give you a normal in the opposite direction.

**Comment by [m4nh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28371/m4nh/) on 2016-10-29**:
Yes! It looks like flat from every vantage point. Reversing order of triangle makes all mesh go away.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
RViz will not show any material / texture if there is no valid transform from whatever *Fixed Frame* is set to and the value you have set in the `header.frame_id` field. Could you include a snippet of how you setup your `Marker` msg? And describe the rest of your TF tree?

**Comment by [m4nh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28371/m4nh/) on 2016-10-29**:
In this example is just a simple node with no TF tree behind. I just set frame_id as `"world"` and set "world" as base frame in Rviz.. so i think is an Identity transform... could this be the problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
If RViz is set to use `world` as the *Fixed Frame*, then things should be ok. Make sure RViz doesn't complain about anything.

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-08-11**:
This looks like how a mesh shows up when it doesn't have any transforms. e.g. a RobotModel with no state publisher or tf publisher behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is resolved by removing colors per each vertex! If you resize `marker.colors` array to the same size of `marker.points` array (and choose some color for each vertex) the color of rendered faces is forced to ignore light and shader. Leave colors array void and change only the `marker.color` parameter to paint your mesh.

---

Originally posted by [m4nh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28371/m4nh/) with karma: 26 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
hm. Is that as this is/was intended @William?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-10-29**:
I don't know. So you're saying the per color vertex is broken?

**Comment by [m4nh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28371/m4nh/) on 2016-10-29**:
the result of "per color vertex" method is the one shown in the attached figure

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-30**:
Could you perhaps add a MWE to your question, or make one available on github? That would make reproducing this a lot easier.

**Comment by [m4nh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28371/m4nh/) on 2016-10-30**:
@gvdhoorn this is the example node: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18830822/triangles_bug.cpp    there is an external parameter `per_vertex_color` (bool) to activate/deactivate the malfunctioning.